# Consequences of a stable geon

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

What would be the consequences be of a stable [geon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics))? What similiarity, if any, would it have to a [naked singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_singularity)? What would a stable geon potentially look like, and what would the immediate surrounding effects be? Would there be, however small, gravitational distortions? Time dilation? Is there anything that a stable geon would teach us about GR or Quantum Gravity?